# Ansible async task collecting results: could not find job

Tags: ansible, fire-and-forget

I'm trying to fire-and-forget some tasks and collect results after that. Here's my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: node2
  gather_facts: yes 
  tasks:
    - name: 'Some long script no 1 on node2'
      shell: "time sleep $[ ( $RANDOM % 20 )  + 20 ]s" 
      async: 40
      poll: 0
      register: script1 

    - name: 'Another long script no 2 on node2'
      shell: "time sleep $[ ( $RANDOM % 20 )  + 20 ]s" 
      async: 40
      poll: 0
      register: script2

- hosts: node2
  tasks:
    - name: "Collect results"
      async_status:
        jid: loop_item.ansible_job_id
      loop:
        - script1
        - script2
      loop_control:
        loop_var: loop_item
      register: async_poll_results
      until: async_poll_results.finished
      retries: 30
```

When I run it, I receive following error:

```
PLAY [node2]     ****************************************************************************************************************************
TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [hostname]

TASK [Some long script no 1 on node2] ***************************************************************************************************
changed: [hostname] => {"ansible_job_id": "814448842231.125544", "changed": true, "finished": 0, "results_file": "/home/external.kamil.sacharczuk/.ansible_async/814448842231.125544", "started": 1}

TASK [Another long script no 2 on node2] ************************************************************************************************
changed: [hostname] => {"ansible_job_id": "586999441005.125616", "changed": true, "finished": 0, "results_file": "/home/external.kamil.sacharczuk/.ansible_async/586999441005.125616", "started": 1}

PLAY [node2] ****************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [hostname]

TASK [Collect results] ******************************************************************************************************************
failed: [hostname] (item=script1) => {"ansible_job_id": "loop_item.ansible_job_id", "attempts": 1, "changed": false, "finished": 1, "loop_item": "script1", "msg": "could not find job", "started": 1}
failed: [hostname] (item=script2) => {"ansible_job_id": "loop_item.ansible_job_id", "attempts": 1, "changed": false, "finished": 1, "loop_item": "script2", "msg": "could not find job", "started": 1}
to retry, use: --limit @xxxxxxxxx

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************
hostname         : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Don't really know why I receive this "could not find job". I tried to run this "collect" tasks localy first, than I figured out, that this job results are stored on node2, so I run it there. Tried with or without gathering facts. Tried also use

```
hostvars['hostname'][loop_item][ansible_job_id]
```

but this gave me same error as here.

Any help would be much appreciated!

PS. I am running ansible 2.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try as below with proper quotation::

```
   - hosts: localhost
     gather_facts: false
     tasks:
      - name: 'Some long script no 1 on node2'
        shell: "time sleep $[ ( $RANDOM % 20 )  + 20 ]s"
        async: 40
        poll: 0
        register: script1

      - name: 'Another long script no 2 on node2'
        shell: "time sleep $[ ( $RANDOM % 20 )  + 20 ]s"
        async: 40
        poll: 0
        register: script2

   - hosts: localhost
     tasks:
      - name: "Collect results"
        async_status:
           jid: "{{ loop_item.ansible_job_id }}"
        loop:
           - "{{ script1 }}"
           - "{{ script2 }}"
        loop_control:
           loop_var: loop_item
        register: async_poll_results
        until: async_poll_results.finished
        retries: 30
```

Answer (score 20):

If someone got here searching for this error message, there is another reason for 'could not find job'. If job was run as `become`, so should be an `async_status`. If you try to async_status for `become`-job without adding `become` to `async_status` module, it will fail with this message.